# Will a background thread that receives a return eventually close itself?

Tags: ios, multithreading, multitasking

It looks like if a background thread is running when you hit the home button, things are suspended and then resumed when reopening the app. I simply want things to stop when the home button is pressed so that on resume, the user can start things from the beginning. After doing some research, it looks like a simple bool flag to periodically check is the way to go. My question, is the part after that. I have the flag part working using some of the notifications like UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, but my question is what action to take to actually stop things. I can do a simple return to stop things, but how does that affect the thread itself? As a general question, if nothing is running, or it gets to the end of the code, will the thread close itself? Or is some sort of explicit exit call needed? In my rough testing, that thread seems to go away, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a thread whose entry point returns, your thread will close. If you install a runloop, your thread may never close, depending on your implementation. In any case, when an app enters background, the main thread is allowed to complete the current runloop run and then the app is suspended. All other threads are suspended also. Once your app returns to the foreground, or when woken up in the background under certain circumstances, your thread will resume work until you end the entry point, suspend it or your app is suspended again.

This is a simplification, of course. In some instances, threads are reused, even if your provided entry point returns. This is the case of thread pools, GCD, etc. In these cases, a thread may appear as alive, but it is actually suspended and takes little resources.

Comment: thanks so much for the quick response, i really appreciate it! I'm not totally clear on how i have an "entry point" setup, so just wanted to check and make sure a return would close mine (don't have a runloop setup). what does it mean exactly to have "a thread whose entry point returns"? my executions in the background thread are very sequential and are all kicked off with a performselectorinbackground. when i debug and walk thru, it backs up all the way to the first call, so can i assume it'll close?

Comment: When you call `performSelectorInBackground:`, the system creates an entry point for you, and then calls your selector from there. Once your selector returns, the system's implemented entry point also returns as it has done its job.

Comment: okay, cool, that seemed to be what my debugging showed, but wasn't totally sure. thanks so much. so when applicationWillResignActive is called, i can set a value. then when my app reopens, i can check that value and stop so that things don't continue processing?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you update that value in a thread-safe manner. Google about `@synchronized`, for example.

Comment: ahh ok, in my applicationWillResignActive, i user nsuserdefaults, set the key and synchronize, i thought that was thread safe, but would that not work correctly? thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I am not sure how thread-safe it is. If it is, it should work. But be careful when setting up your thread. Polling in a loop can be very CPU intensive. Consider a more complex design.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41489/discussion-between-andrew-gray-and-leo-natan)